# How to represent the symmetric part of the outer product of two vectors represented as the outer product of two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, outer-product

Consider a matrix,
$$M = x y^{\top}.$$

Say,
$$M_{\text{sym.}} = xy^{\top}+yx^{\top}$$
is the symmetric part of $M$.

How can one represent $M_{\text{sym.}}$ in the form
$$M_{\text{sym.}} = zz^{\top},$$
where $z$ is a function of vectors $x$ and $y$:
$$z = f(x,y)?$$

P.S.:  Assume all vectors have appropriate dimensions.

Comment: You can’t. The matrix $xy^\top+yx^\top$ can easily be rank $2$, whereas a single outer product will be of rank (at most) $1$.

Comment: You can only do it if $x$ and $y$ are collinear, or if $p$, $q$ are matrices .  Specifically, write $p$ as the $2*n$ matrix $(x,y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $q$ as the $2*n$ matrix $(y,x)\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}$, where the $x$, $y$ vectors act as columns of the matrices.

Comment: ^thank you for the comments. I understand your points. 
But is it theoretically impossible? I just want to make sure before leaving it, as I am really not good at this.

Comment: @AbhiramVP The point is that it's *generally* not possible. There may be a few special cases where it is possible.

Comment: It's not impossible but cases where it works are less interesting since it forces things like $y=\lambda x$ for some scalar $\lambda$.